# Setting initial supply for token through myetherwallet

Tags: ethereum, wallet

I've tried creating a new crypto token with myetherwallet and it works, except the initial supply is incorrect. I've asked 100,000,000,000 and only got 1000,000 .

I setting the initial supply possible through myetherwallet or should I use Myst?

Here's how I created the contract:

1. in myst

   ```
   pragma solidity ^0.4.8;
   contract tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 
   _value, address _token, bytes _extraData); }

   contract ForCoin {
   /* Public variables of the token */
   string public standard = 'ForCoin 0.1';
   string public name;
   string public symbol;
   uint8 public decimals;
   uint256 public totalSupply;

   /* This creates an array with all balances */
   mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
   mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

   /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients 
   */
   event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

   /* This notifies clients about the amount burnt */
   event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

   /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the 
   contract */
   function ForCoin(
       uint256 initialSupply,
       string tokenName,
       uint8 decimalUnits,
       string tokenSymbol
       ) {
       initialSupply = 100000000000;
       balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator 
   all initial tokens
       totalSupply = initialSupply;                        // Update total 
   supply
       name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for 
   display purposes
       symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol 
   for display purposes
       decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of 
   decimals for display purposes
   }
   ```
2. Copy code to myetherwallet and deploy.

Remark: I've also filled out the initial supply value in myst itself on the right hand side.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You must have given decimal places as 5.

Comment: And where would they have done that? How can they check?

Comment: Please add more info. This is not very helpful.